# how to make following div responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

[I want to make this responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY6li.jpg)
**I have designed this in html and css and i want to make this div responsive... How can I do?

I tried by using bootstrap columns but it doesn't work

And also tell me how to make background responsive if it has a background image of fixed height.

```css
.im1
{
  /*padding: 10px;*/
  /*margin-left: 60px;*/
  margin-top: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-right: -80px;
}

.background1 {
  background: url("../car/car_web.jpg");
  /*border: 2px solid black;*/
  width:1380px;
  height:350px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 130px;
  left: 0px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  /*top: 20px;*/
  margin-left: -155px;
    
}
```

```html
<section id="COMPARE" style="margin-left: 100px;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12 background1">
        <label class="ll">
      <center><small><strong>Car Comparison lorims info</strong></small>
        <h3>Compare Cars</h3>
      </center>
      </label><br>
         
<div class="im1 col-md-3" style="position:relative; margin-left:40px;">
              <img class="" src="car/1.jpg" width="200px;" height="120px;" style=" position:absolute; z-index=1; top:0px; left:80px;">
              <img src="icon/vs.png" width="55px" height="55px" style="position:absolute; top:30px; left:260px; z-index:3;">
              <img class="" src="car/2.jpg" width="200px;" height="120px;" style=" position:absolute; z-index=1; top:0px; left:300px;">
              <img src="icon/vs.png" width="55px" height="55px" style="position:absolute; top:30px; left:480px; z-index:3;">
              <img class="" src="car/3.jpg" width="200px;" height="120px;" style=" position:absolute; z-index=1; top:0px; left:520px;">
               <img src="icon/vs.png" width="55px" height="55px" style="position:absolute; top:30px; left:700px; z-index:3;">
              <img class="" src="car/4.jpg" width="200px;" height="120px;" style=" position:absolute; z-index=1; top:0px; left:740px;">  
             </div>
          
          
          <div class="col-md-12 de" id="compare">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary12 btn-lg outline1 " name="login">COMPARE CARS</button></span>
            <br>
            <br>
            <small><strong>Or <a href="#">Click here for custom comparison</a></strong></small>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: share your codes??

Comment: Please include code that you currently have

Comment: You should have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: iether you make the div's css in percent or you learn about [@media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: I dont know how to add html code? I cant able to upload it

Comment: Copy your code, paste it in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very difficult to see the issue without looking at how you've coded it unfortunately, could you copy in your code so we can see how you've got things setup?

However, I will give it a go. I'm going to assume that the four vehicles are in a wrapper div and that you want the images of the vehicles to fall beneath each other when the window gets smaller.. something like this:

```
/* Standard size */
.carImage{
   width: 25%;
}

/* Tablet Size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .carImage{
      width: 50%;
   }
}

/* Mobile Size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   .carImage{
      width: 100%;
   }
}
```

Change the `.carImage` to whatever class you have for each car image - but once again I can't tell the exact problem unless you paste your code in. If this doesn't help copy the code in and I will try again.

EDIT: After looking at the code you sent:

https://jsfiddle.net/o05yvL1h/3/

I wouldn't use `position: absolute;` in the way you've done it, I don't use it very often personally so maybe this won't help, but maybe it will - just a quick example of how you might go about it. I've changed the image sources just for an example, Hope it helps...

Comment: Thnks... I have paste my code can you please suggest better with new code?

Comment: Check out the JS fiddle with for a sample - hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks... Its working for car and vs class.... Now How to make background image responsive? I have used background1 class for that...

Comment: I would probably add `width: 100%;` to allow the div to scale. Then maybe add `background-size: cover;` to ensure the image covers the div. Add this to the `.background1` I think :-)

Answer (score 3):

https://jsfiddle.net/o05yvL1h/
https://jsfiddle.net/o05yvL1h/2/

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 23%;
  width: calc(25% - 1em);
  margin: 1em .5em;
  background: silver;
  line-height: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

div + div:after {
  content: "VS";
  line-height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  margin: -1em;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  top: 50%;
  left: -.5em;
}

@media all and (max-width: 320px) {
  div {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
  }
  
  div + div:after {
    top: -.5em;
    left: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  1
</div><div>
  2
</div><div>
  3
</div><div>
  4
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks... But at mobile device car images can not be seen clear...

Comment: what should i do  to put "vs" below the image if i display car images as per  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   .carImage{
      width: 100%;
   }
}

Comment: @Prasad, `srcset` and `sizes`? https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: @Prasad, added media query.

Comment: thnk u very much.. How to make background image responsive? I have used background1 class for that...